# Wordpress admin unresponsive in local dev environment

Tags: wordpress, performance, localhost, mamp

My local dev environment consists of MAMP, Chrome and Firefox. In certain places in the admin any of my wordpress installs are unreponsive, even with a completely fresh install with no plugins or themes enabled.

What I mean is that once I click a button like "save menu" under appearance->menus, or when I for example try to add three pages to a menu, an request is fired without response. One is an ajax request (the add to Menu Button that is) and another one is just a normal post request (save menu), both actions lead to no response.

I tried to

- Upgrade MAMP
- INcrease my memory_limit in php.ini

And I of course also searched the Internet like crazy for somebody who had a similar problem, to no avail.

Anybody having/had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this had to do with too much messing around with packages on OSX and nothing with php apache or wordpress for that matter. It behaved quite strangely.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing... what did you do to fix this?